# Query for sorting datagrid column by last four digits?

Tags: sql-server, winforms, ms-access-2007

How to display descending order in datagridview, the order must start from after last character.

This is my column in datagridvie "VehicleNo"

ex:

```
1)ap20aa4779

2)ap09ss9999

3)se06ps1136

4)su02rd5544
```

The `DESCENDING order` must start from after last character.

I have the following values from the db :-

```
1)ap09ss9999

2)su02rd5544

3)ap20aa4779

4)se06ps1136
```

`The database is MSACCESS 2007.`

one of my friends suggest this query:-

```
select VehicleNo from ScooterInOut order by reverse(vehicleNo) desc where TokenStatus=0
```

It's working great on `SQL SERVER` but doesn't working on `MsAccess`.

Could u plz Advise...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Access db engine's `Right()` function in your `ORDER BY` expression.

```
SELECT VehicleNo
FROM ScooterInOut
WHERE TokenStatus=0
ORDER BY Right(vehicleNo, 4) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select VehicleNo
 From tblVehicles
 Order By Convert(int,SUBSTRING(VehicleNo,Len(VehicleNo)-3,4)) Desc
```

Comment: thanks for your reply... but i getting this error "IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)." im using ms Access as backend

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do the sorting on the client i.e. the Datagridview after you have fetched the data. Then you won't have any SQL SERVER / MSACCESS / Oracle kind of dependency. 
Query the data, bind to DatagridView and then apply the sort on the grid view.

So, you may leave your query like this -

`select VehicleNo from ScooterInOut where TokenStatus=0` which is a pretty standard query. And, then apply the [sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608.aspx) on Datagridview after binding the data.

Read msdn, it has all the information on how to achieve this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171607.aspx

Performance worries - I assume you would have thought of querying in batches, applied paging & stuff and if it is a large dataset then you might have thought of virtualizing the datagridview, etc,etc..